# update fragment from dialogfragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I am using textview text from a SQLite database in fragment. Now I want to update textview when SQLite database is updated. I am using an alertdialog for updating the SQLite database. When I click the save button then database is updated, but textview does not update until reload the fragment.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    user = db.getUserDetails();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflating view layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    proName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.proName);
    proChangePassword = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.proChangePassword);

    proName.setText(user.get("fname") + " " + user.get("lname"));

    return v;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.profile_edit:
            profileEdit();
            return false;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return false;
}


private void profileEdit() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_edit, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    eFirstName = (TextInputLayout) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.pEditFirst);
    eLastName = (TextInputLayout) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.pEditLast);
    final Button pEditSave = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.pEditSave);

    eFirstName.getEditText().setText(user.get("fname"));
    eLastName.getEditText().setText(user.get("lname"));

    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Profile Edit");
    final AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();

    pEditSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String fname = eFirstName.getEditText().getText().toString();
            String lname = eLastName.getEditText().getText().toString();

            db.updateProfile(fname,lname);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Profile is successfully updated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

How to auto refresh fragment when click dialog's save button?

Answer (score 1):

Using interface concept its possible to reload fragment in activity on Dismiss of Custom Dialog Fragment

> 1.Define interface which contains method like below

```
public interface IdialogDismissFragmentReload {
  public void onDismisClick();
  }
```

> 2.`Fragment A extends Fragment implements IdialogDismissFragmentReload`  this is the place from where you are going to update fragment

```
 Fragment A extends Fragment implements IdialogDismissFragmentReload  
  interface 
   {
  ......
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  FragmentB mFragmentB = new FragmentB ();
  mFragmentB .setListener(this);
  mFragmentB.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),PreviewDialog");
}

 @Override
 public void onDismisClick() {
  //  write code you want to
}
}
```

> 3.On dismiss ,it call the `Fragment A` `onDismisClick()` methos whre you can write your updated code, also you can pass required data from B to A

```
3.FragmentB extends DialogFragment
{
 private IdialogDismissFragmentReload mIReminderAdded;

public void setListener(IdialogDismissFragmentReload listener) {
    mIReminderAdded = listener;
  }

........

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 mIReminderAdded.onDismisClick();
 getDialog().dismiss();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onResume` of `Fragment` to read the database and update UI. Thus move database query and user updation from `onCreate` to `onResume`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    user = db.getUserDetails();
}
```

Whenever you will close the `Alert Dialog`, `onResume` will be called and data will be updated.